# Cannot use Ruble sign on Russian keyboard layout

Tags: keyboard, russian

With a Russian keyboard layout, I cannot access the Russian Ruble symbol ₽ with <kbd>Alt Gr</kbd> + <kbd>8</kbd>.

Does anyone have a solution for this, or is this fixed in newer Ubuntu versions?
I use Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS.

Comment: What is your desktop environment?

Comment: My desktop is Xfce.

Comment: See below. You have to use low level method.

Comment: Thank you for your support.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The final solution depends on the desktop environment in use:

- For Cinnamon you need to

  1. Make left mouse click on layout switcher in tray, select *Keyboard Settings*
  2. Go to *Layouts* tab
  3. Click *Options*
  4. Set *Key to choose the 3rd level* to *Right Alt*
  5. Click *Close*
  6. Close Keyboard configuration window
  7. Switch keyboard layout to Russian
  8. Click <kbd>RightAlt</kbd>+<kbd>8</kbd> to write the Ruble symbol (₽)
- For KDE you need to

  1. Make right mouse click on layout switcher in tray, select *Configure Layouts*
  2. Go to *Advanced* tab
  3. Check *Configure keyboard options*
  4. Set *Key to choose the 3rd level* to *Right Alt*
  5. Click *OK*
  6. Switch keyboard layout to Russian
  7. Click <kbd>RightAlt</kbd>+<kbd>8</kbd> to write the Ruble symbol (₽)
- For GNOME desktop you need to

  1. Install GNOME Tweaks by `sudo apt-get install gnome-tweaks`
  2. Launch Tweaks application
  3. Go to *Keyboard & Mouse* tab
  4. Click on *Additional Layout Options*
  5. Set *Key to choose the 3rd level* to *Right Alt*
  6. Close *Additional Layout Options* window and close Tweaks application
  7. Switch keyboard layout to Russian
  8. Click <kbd>RightAlt</kbd>+<kbd>8</kbd> to write the Ruble symbol (₽)
- For MATE desktop you need to set this in Keyboard Preferences (`mate-keyboard-properties`):

  1. On *Layouts* tab add *Russian* keyboard layout
  2. Click *Options*
  3. Set *Key to choose the 3rd level* to *Right Alt*
  4. Close *Keyboard Preferences* window
  5. Switch keyboard layout to Russian
  6. Click <kbd>RightAlt</kbd>+<kbd>8</kbd> to write the Ruble symbol (₽)
- For Xfce, LXDE, LxQT:

  1. Open terminal
  2. Open Nano editor to edit keyboard configuration file by `sudo nano /etc/default/keyboard`
  3. Add `lv3:ralt_switch` to the `XKBOPTIONS` variable
  4. Save the file with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd>, close editor with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>
  5. Rebuild initrams with `sudo update-initramfs -u -k all`
  6. Reboot and login to desktop session
  7. Switch keyboard layout to Russian
  8. Click <kbd>RightAlt</kbd>+<kbd>8</kbd> to write the Ruble symbol (₽)